# monit syntax error on SSL

Tags: monit

I am trying to use gmail as my mail server for alert messages in monit. I have these lines in monitrc:

```
set mailserver smtp.gmail.com
  port 587
  username "myusername" password "mypassword"
  using SSL
```

I always get the following error.

```
 /etc/monit/monitrc:59: Error: syntax error 'SSL'
```

I am using monit 5.6 and I copied the recipe from https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Gmail

Comment: Having the same issue with Monit v5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine with monit 5.20.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a bug, i had it on version 5.2.5 (Centos 7 on Amazon Linux)

Please use the latest version (as of now 5.21.0) and it will work, as adviesd by the recipe.